# Unable to setup AutoMapper in Unit Test, Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to create a Unit Test class using xUnit in my .Net Core 2.1 Razor Pages project and I seem to be having trouble creating an AutoMapper `IMapper` object to pass back to the methods I want to test.

Here is a simplified version of my AutoMapper profile in `MainProject.csproj/AutoMapper/DomainProfile.cs`

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using MainProject.Models;
using MainProject.Models.ViewModels;

namespace MainProject.AutoMapper
{
    // Ref: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/
    // AutoMapper (called from Startup.cs) will search for any class that inherits from Profile
    public class DomainProfile : Profile
    {
        public DomainProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<MyModel, MyViewModel>()
                .ForMember(vm => vm.Property1, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Property1))
                .ForMember(vm => vm.Property2, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Property2))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Unsure if it matters, but here is my `MainProject.csproj/Startup.cs`'s `ConfigureServices` method where the Dependency Injection for AutoMapper get's setup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => { ... });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // AutoMapper
    services.AddAutoMapper();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => { ... })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Finally, here is my stripped down test class I've been trying to get working, `MainProject.Test.csproj/Services/MyModelServicesTest.cs`:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Outreach.AutoMapper;
using Xunit;
...
...

namespace MainProject.Test.Services
{
    public class MyModelServicesTest
    {

        [Fact]
        public async Task MyUnitTestMethod()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new DomainProfile());
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            // myModelServices.SomeMethod(mapper);
            // ... Other code that is never reached before the error throws
        }
    }
}
```

When the code hits `cfg.AddProfile(new DomainProfile());` it throws this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

According to the error message, it could be that `AspNetCore` dependency is missing. For example, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` in 2.0 or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in 2.1.

I normally inject AutoMapper to Controller. Then use the following [approach](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Tests/Asp.Web.Tests/Controllers/UsersControllerTests.cs#L98) to unit test a controller.

```
public class MyModelServicesTest
{
   private readonly Mapper _mapper;

   public MyModelServicesTest()
   {
      _mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
           cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())));
   }

   [Fact]
   public async Task MyUnitTestMethod()
   {
       var sut = new SomeController(_mapper, _mockSomeRepository.Object);
   }
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, I'm doing nearly the same thing as you aside from a couple things: I'm using a plain class called `MyModelServices` that I'm injecting an `IMapper` into, instead of a Controller. Your `cfg => ...` statement is a little different, but changing mine to that didn't seem to change anything. Is `MappingProfile` your version of my `DomainProfile`?

Comment: `Is MappingProfile your version of my DomainProfile?` Yes. The exception message is about AspNetCore dependeny. Could you ensure you reference AspNetCore in Unit Test project such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`?

Comment: I think you're right, but since I'm targeting .Net Core 2.1, I need to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` based on the notice at the top of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.1 But after installing that to my Test project (and getting the version to match that of my Main project) I got past my AutoMapper config error! Thank you!

Comment: If you update your answer to suggest installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to my test project I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @RyanTaite I'm glad that you figure out the issue. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Win, your post suggests to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, which is better for 2.0 apps, instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, which is better for 2.1+ apps like mine according to that link I posted earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Try explicitly passing the type in for AutoMapper:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup), ///additional types where you can find profiles));
```

Without the type, the extension will scan loaded assemblies. That seems to cause problems in unit tests, so to be safe be explicit about where to look for `Profile` instances.

Comment: Hey Jimmy, it looks like my issue was more about not having a reference in my test project to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, as Win figured out. But I recreated my problem and changed my `services.AddAutoMapper();` to `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));` and still got the same error. Unsure if this approach would solve this or what other types to supply there, if any.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I added

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.1" />
```

To the xUnit project file and

rebuild the solution and unit tests didn't give me that error anymore.