# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.CoreLib.Net

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, integration, xunit

I created an XUnit Test for integration testing and followed the example here ([Integration Tests in ASP.NET Core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gi1O.png))
This loads the Startup of the mvc project but fails with an exception where auto mapper is being injected.

Any ideas on what this means?

[![Exception User-Unhandled][2]][2]

Test Class

```
// WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> is used to create a TestServer for the integration tests.
public class ServiceHttpClientTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public ServiceHttpClientTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/Index")]
    [InlineData("/About")]
    [InlineData("/Contact")]
    [InlineData("/Privacy")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}



enter code here
```

Project File
[image]

Comment: What does your test project’s csproj file look like?

Comment: Updated my post. I tried using preview of Test.Sdk as per Neil's answer but gave same error.

Comment: If you change your target framework to `net5.0` does anything change?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just now. There is a bug in Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.9.1. The immediate fix is to update the nuget package to the preview version (until they release the new version).

src: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2791

Comment: Was your issue also on AutoMapper injection? If I comment out that line the error goes away.

Comment: No it wasn't. I'm glad you found the correct solution though

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was Auto Mapper, scanning the loaded assemblies to determine a Type. So I followed the solution give by Jimmy Bogard on this post: [Unable to setup AutoMapper in Unit Test ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007892/unable-to-setup-automapper-in-unit-test-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microso)

I implemented the following in my presentation startup file and the unit test ran perfectly!

```
services.AddAutoMapper(**typeof(Startup)**);
```